# Using views to display complex content

Tags: 8

I am using Drupal 8 to build a little complex website. Here is an example of what the content is like:

Content Types: Books, Chapters, Paragraphs
For instance a book content type would contain fields to hold author, cover pic, etc. then the chapter will have a link to the related book, and paragraphs will have links to its related chapter and an ordering number.

Now I'd like to have the website to have pages as following:

- `/books` - will show all books by cover photo with links to go to the contents
- `/books/<book-name>` - will show info about a specific book with list of chapters each with a link to go to the content of that chapter
- `/books/<book-name>/<chapter-number>` - Will show all paragraphs in that chapter

My question is can this be achieved just by the view module that is installed with d8 vanilla?
Can I achieve all of this with one view? If multiple views are needed, can they all use the same path structure (/books is common in that case)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this can be achieved by using views module. And the structure should go something like:
a. Content Type Book.
b. Content Type Chapter.

Now chapter CT will have node references field of CT Book.

Create a view of books content type which will show all books then create a page within same view with some changed filters to show /books/book-name.

Now create another view  with link /books/book-name/chapter-number where book-name will match the node reference field or /books/book-name/ from previous view to get book name.

Comment: Regarding the last sentence, create another view with link /books/book-name/chapter-number, does it mean to create a view for each book?

Comment: No it means create a single view dynamically by getting bookname from contextual filters and convert it to node id

Comment: How would Drupal pick the correct view/page when the url `/books` is requested? I mean I am yet to try it but just wondering

Comment: you have to define a path i.e. when you create a view with page option under page settings there is an option called path, where you can define your views path for ex; books, books/% where % is wildcard.